# Windows 10 installation not booting from USB: "Reboot and select proper boot device ..."

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, asus

I'm trying to install Win 10 from a 128 GB USB stick, without success.

When the PC starts, this is what I see right after ASUS logo etc.:

> Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected
> boot device and press a key

What I've tried:

- Changed the USB stick to be the first in the boot order of UEFI.
- Different USB ports.
- Testing that the stick is working on another (newer) laptop. No issues - installation starts just fine.
- Reformat the USB stick and creating the necessary files from scratch several times.
- Looked for anything related to Secure Boot, Fast Boot and CSM. Can't find any of these in the UEFI. Motherboard is ASUS P8P67-M PRO.
- Reset UEFI to factory defaults, and changed to boot order again. Still no luck.
- Disabling legacy USB support in UEFI.

The PC has been running Linux for several years without any issues - and still does.

Comment: The age of the hardware strongly suggests is has BIOS, not UEFI. That being the case most of what you reported isn't applicable. Two problems can be happening here, by themselves or concomitantly: 1. The flash drive is too big / too new 2. Depending on how you made the installation media it may not boot in BIOS mode (If you used Rufus with UEFI/GPT settings that would be the case). Find a smaller, older yet known good, preferably USB2.0 stick and preferably use the Windows official Media Creation tool that's triggered when downloading th ISO from a Windows system.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not an expert on the matter, but according to multiple sources it is a UEFI (e.g. https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16813131707 `The new ASUS EFI BIOS is an Extensible Firmware Interface that complies with uEFI architecture`. But I'll try to get my hands on smaller USB 2.0 stick.

Comment: Whatever the firmware is update it to the latest version, just in case. And yes, checking *your* user's manual and seeing all the flashy graphics in the settings interface, we should conclude it's UEFI but - it can be a problem - a very early implementation, hence the recommendation to update it to the latest version. Also enabling both Legacy USB and Legacy USB3.0 support is recommended. Other than that and what I commented before about the stick itself I can't imagine any other problem preventing it to boot. Another recommendation: Don't change the boot order in the UEFI settings (...)

Comment: (...) keep it set to the target drive for the installation and use F8 (one time boot menu / boot override menu) to select the USB drive and if it isn't listed then reboot and try again. Reason: Some motherboards have issues detecting bootable USB drives from a cold boot.

Comment: 128 GB USB flash drive is likely formatted exFAT, which may not be readable in BIOS/UEFI setup. Format it FAT32, and use the Windows Media Creation Tool if you can (perhaps from a friend's Windows PC). Note that Rufus is no blocked from fetching the ISO!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ChanganAuto I tried with a USB 2.0 stick and also updated the BIOS/UEFI. But no luck.

Created a new installation using Rufus, instead of the built-in one in Ubuntu. This worked! However it could be a combination of the USE 2.0 and UEFI also getting updated.